# Automate the AWS Glue workflow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-forecast

What are the different ways to automate the AWS Glue workflow, I've data in AWS S3,now I've to automate the AWS Glue workflow (that does the Amazon Forecast and write back the results to AWS S3)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a trigger in the aws workflow which provides you with three options

1. Using Events as a trigger, where events can be any cloudwatch event. So you can setup something like as soon as file arrives in s3 trigger the workflow.
2. Using time based schedule,, this will trigger the job at the desired time on the desired interval.
3. On demand, trigger the workflow whenever required.

Alternatively you can also use step functions to automate your glue jobs.